# Cannot edit strings in make file

Tags: shell, makefile

I have the following code in make file:

```
All:CheckOutFolder
echo "Starting Build";
@for entry in ${DIR};                                       \
do                                                          \
    for i in $${entry}/*.[cs];                              \
    do                                                      \
    echo "Bulding $${i}";                                   \
    arm-none-eabi-gcc ${OPT} $${i} -c -o ${OUT}/${${$${i}##*/}:-1}.o;   \
    done                                                    \
done
```

The problem is that `${${$${i}##*/}:-1}.o` generates empty string.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You shouldn't ask the same question twice, but rather edit your other question "Manipulating string in makefile".

Answer (score 1):

You have a conceptual problem here: you are mixing Make functions inside of code that is run in a shell. Things like `FILE=$(notdir $(i))` will be expanded *once* before the shell script is run, not in each loop iteration inside the shell script.

Instead what is typically done is to expand the list of things you want to iterate outside of the target, the thing that starts `@for`. The [foreach](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html) function can help you there.

Lastly, it is for these kinds of problems that [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) was written. It has a debugger in it. So you can stop at the target "All" and write out the code that will get run. And then it is more clear that functions like "notdir" and "substr" do not appear in the shell code that gets run.

```
remake -X Makefile All
GNU Make 4.1+dbg0.91
...
Updating goal targets....
remake: Nothing to be done for 'Makefile'.
-> (/tmp/Makefile:2)
All: 
remake<0> write
File "/tmp/All.sh" written.
```

Now look at /tmp/All.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
#/tmp/Makefile:2
#cd /tmp
echo "Starting Build";
@for entry in ;                                       \
    do                                                          \
        for i in ${entry}/*.[cs];                              \
        do                                                      \
        echo "Bulding ${i}";                                   \
        FILE=;                            \
        FILE= ;                                     \
        echo "";                                         \
        arm-none-eabi-gcc  ${i} -c -o /;    \
        done                                                    \
    done
```

In trying some things on the above example, <strike>I see that remake's "set" command has a bug that SEGVs, which I'll look into sometime.</strike> (Bug fixed in remake-4.1+dbg1.1)

Comment: i've edited my code could you tell me why `${${$${i}##*/}:-1}.o` generates file named ".o" only

Comment: More interesting I think is if you can tell yourself by using remake. Try that and let me know how that goes. The 'eval', 'expand' and 'print' commands are your friends here.